# How to tilt an element by distorting it?

Tags: html, css

How can I distort my card (img element) to look like the image on the right?

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNSF0.png)

Let's say, on the card:

- A is the top left
- B is the top right
- C is the bottom left
- D is the bottom right

What I want:

- A and B to be closer to each other
- C and D to be farther from each other
- Squish the card vertically making the top (A and B) and the bottom (C and D) parts closer to each other vertically

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5rem;
}

.card {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    background: red;
    height: 250px;
    width: 190px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is examle of transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(45deg);

```css
 .el {
        margin: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(45deg);
      }
```

```html
<div class="el"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt=""></div>
```